# Img tag not uploading img with src tag

Tags: html, css, image, src

I'm new to coding and cannot figure out what the problem is. Code is below. I'm making a moc website for practice and the picture outline used to be present but now nothing appears. Super confused

```
<div id="content">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="about">
                <div class="about-author">
                    <img src="IMG_0017.jpg" width="300px" height="300px">
                </div>
```

Comment: Is the image in the right folder?

Comment: Are there any errors reported if you look at your browser's inspect facility console?

Comment: Do you have more code, and are is that your full code (i.e. are the tags balanced ?).  The path to the image file, IMG_0017.jpg, has to be "correct".  If it is the same directory as the referencing page that is probably OK.  You should learn how to use dev tools in the browser and look at the network tab.  You are probably getting a 404 error ?